# Backup database from C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that works fine when I run it when using Windows authentication. If I run it as the standard website user it fails, I guessed it was a permissions thing. So I'm trying to add a script in that allows me to connect to the database from C# and run the backup using Windows auth.

```
public bool BackUpDataBase()
{
    string connString = _country == Country.England ? _connectionStringSiteDbEngland : _connectionStringSiteDbScotland;

    try
    {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) 
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("BackupDB", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BaseLocation", _serverBackupLocation));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BackupType", _backupType));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;
            }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //FAILED :(
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get a timeout error on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`. The same connection string allows me to connect the the database to query a table here.

```
public bool IsScheduled()
{
        string archiveDB = _country == Country.England ? _englandArchiveDBName : _scotlandArchiveDBName;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_country == Country.England ? _connectionStringSiteDbEngland : _connectionStringSiteDbScotland)) 
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand(SQLToCheckSchedule(), conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            int rows = 0;

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
               while (rdr.Read())
               {
                    rows++;
               }
            }  

            conn.Close();

            return rows > 0;
        }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you'd show the actual error and what you have tried to resolve it.

Comment: {"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}

Comment: Yeah. The backup likely takes more time than allowed as per command / conection settings. It really helps to READ the error message.

Comment: Shouldn't backups be the database's concern, not the application's?

Answer (score 3):

Your database backup process simply takes too long compared to a regular table query. You can set the command timeout via the [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000; //This is in seconds
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The default is 30 seconds. You can also set it to 0 so that it would wait indefinitely. However, this is a bit dangerous as this may lock your site/app. You may want to set your backup processes somewhere else instead, such as a scheduled task.